# JSON Schema - specify string length based on input property

Tags: jsonschema

Is it possible with JSON Schema to specify a string length that depends on the value of a property in the item that is being validated?

For example, I have a document with a "foo" property with value 3. I would like to ensure that the "bar" property is a string of at least size 3

**Sample JSON**

```
{
"foo": 3,
"bar": "111"
}
```

**JSON Schema**

```
{
   "properties" : {
      "foo": {
         "type": "integer",
         "minimum": 1
       }
      "bar": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": "{$foo}"
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a v5 [proposal for a `$data` keyword](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/%24data-(v5-proposal)) that would "*allow schemas to use values from the data, specified using JSON Pointers or Relative JSON Pointers*".

Using your example:

```
{
   "properties" : {
      "foo": {
         "type": "integer",
         "minimum": 1
       }
      "bar": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": { "$data": "1/foo" }
       }
   }
}
```

Support for the `$data` keyword will obviously depend upon the validator you are using. Some validators do support the v5 proposals.

Comment: It seems like the `$data` keyword hasn't been accepted and probably won't be in the near future. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: It seems `$data` keeps getting pushed to the next draft. It's now talked about for draft 9: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51#issuecomment-344624488